# Can iphone mix two sound files or build custom equalizer?

Tags: iphone

Can iphone mix two sound files or build custom equalizer? 
I have studied for weeks about this problem, 
and it seems unable to use iphone-sdk to mix two or more sound files or to build custom equalizer. 
Is anyone have the experience to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. AVAudioPlayer can play multiple sounds and you can control the volume for each. Or you can use Audio Units and have more control over the audio data.

aurioTouch is a good sample app for what you are thinking of.

Comment: hide comments
Sorry, I think that I missing an important point, which is how can I mix two sound files "into one file". Is any samples that I can follow? thx

Answer (score 0):

For simple playback of sound files you can use the AVAudioPlayer class introduced in the 2.2 SDK. It provides playback and volume controls for playing any audio file. As far as I am aware, there are no restrictions on the number of sound files you can play on the iPhone. The only restriction on playing sound files is that you may only play one AAC or MP3 compressed file at a time, the rest of the files must be either uncompressed or in the IMA4 format.

If your needs are more low-level (If you need to do DSP) you might want to look at AudioQueue Services or AudioUnits - two Mac OS X audio processing APIs that are also available on the iPhone.